# Keyboard shortcut for Force Quitting the current application?

Tags: mac, keyboard

Instead of pressing `Command + Option + Esc` to bring up the Force Quit menu, is there a way that I can force quit the application that I'm currently using directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it – the keyboard shortcut I was looking for was `Command + Option + Shift + Esc`. This will quit the frozen app as long as it's in focus.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Force Quit dialog opens with the currently running application already selected. So the shortcut is kind of <kbd>Cmd-Opt-Esc</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> (which IMHO is good enough for all practical purposes).

Comment: Never knew it was selected by default.

Comment: Didn’t work for me when I was blocked out of the UI by a misbehaving app.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs if the UI is blocked, the OS ist most likely unable to process any keyboard events anyway.

Comment: @nohillside The issue I encounter frequently is that I'm using Starcraft II on an ARM-based Mac. If the system goes into standby while Starcraft II is active, there's a bug in macOS where the keyboard input is still in Starcraft II, but the lock screen is displayed without any way to enter the password. So I have only keyboard access to the application. Cmd-Opt-Esc has no effect, but another keyboard shortcut does work, force-quitting Starcraft II and returning focus to the login screen.